# Previously valid static method references ignored by Flash 10.1 compiler

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a program that I wrote in ActionScript 3 that I have been compiling without errors up through Flash CS4 (FP10). Now I'm trying to compile for Flash CS5 (FP 10.1?) and am getting crazy errors over what seems to be a mundane point. I wonder if someone could offer insight...

This blocker that I'm getting a 1061 compiler error (`Call to a possibly undefined method parseBoolean through a reference with static type Class`) because it apparently can't read a public static method on a utility class that I wrote. Basic reference structure as follows:

Utility Class:

```
package com.lassie.utils
{
    public final class XMLUtil
    {
        public static function parseBoolean($value:String, $defaultValue:Boolean=false):Boolean {
            if ($value == null || $value == "") return $defaultValue;
            return ($value == "1" || $value == "true");
        }
    }
}
```

Referencing Script:

```
import com.lassie.utils.XMLUtil;

function parseXML($xml:XML, $tween:PuppetTween):PuppetTween
{
    $tween.followGrid = XMLUtil.parseBoolean( $xml.@followGrid, true );
    $tween.animateMoves = XMLUtil.parseBoolean( $xml.@animateMoves, true );
    $tween.confineToWalkarea = XMLUtil.parseBoolean( $xml.@confineToWalkarea, false );
    return $tween;
}
```

For whatever reason, I'm getting hit with an error `1061: Call to a possibly undefined method parseBoolean through a reference with static type Class` for each reference to the static `parseBoolean` helper method. It's like the compiler is completely blind to the fact that the method exists on the `XMLUtil` class, despite it being declared as both public and static. Again, this did work in both Flash 9 and Flash 10 compilers. It's just CS5 that suddenly throws this issue.

Any ideas? Has anyone else had a similar migration issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered this too and in my case it had nothing to do with the member being static, but somehow the compiler got confused because I had used an already existing class name (in a different package though!!!)
The code compiled perfectly in CS4, but broke in CS5.

The solution was to use the fully qualified name:

```
import com.lassie.utils.XMLUtil;

function parseXML($xml:XML, $tween:PuppetTween):PuppetTween
{
    $tween.followGrid = com.lassie.utils.XMLUtil.parseBoolean( $xml.@followGrid, true );
    $tween.animateMoves = com.lassie.utils.XMLUtil.parseBoolean( $xml.@animateMoves, true );
    $tween.confineToWalkarea = com.lassie.utils.XMLUtil.parseBoolean( $xml.@confineToWalkarea, false );
    return $tween;
}
```

I never found out why this happened (and didn't take the time to search for it)
Hope this helps

Comment: The reason is because you are not creating the singleton properly.

Comment: Really, this has nothing to do with singletons.

Comment: You've gotta be kidding me... yep. That worked. I think your theory about classes in different packages sharing the same name may be accurate, too. I was just looking through my codebase: while I only made one class called XMLUtil, I now see that Adobe has one in their corelib as well (which I use in my app). Apparently the compiler doesn't namespace class names the way it used to. Good to know. Thanks for your help! Great answer!

Comment: Just to follow up... classes sharing the same name (even in different packages) is definitely the issue here. I just refactored my application and changed the "XMLUtil" class name to "XmlUtil" so that it no longer conflicts with the name in the Adobe Corelib. Issue solved. I can once again reference members of the class using a single import statement at the top of the referencing class.

Answer (score -2):

When you do this sort of thing you need to remember a Singleton still has one instance.
Here is a good [link](http://chrissilich.com/blog/basic-example-of-an-actionscript-3-singleton/) explaining it.
And more in-depth [here](http://life.neophi.com/danielr/2006/10/singleton_pattern_in_as3.html).
Basically, what you are doing is calling a static function on a class not set up for Singleton use.

If you just want a helper class make your life easy and just make it a normal public class.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it's a singleton? It's a plain old static method and he's calling it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, there's no need for this scenario to use the Singleton pattern. The XMLUtil class just defines a collection of static helper methods, much the way the Math class provides a collection of common math functions.